# Drag a label and make it leave a black trail behind it

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am working on a project and I have a label in a picturebox that I need to drag around and while dragging around have it leave a black trail on the picturebox.  I am stumped as to how to make this happen.  The label is 15x15 and is moved using the mouse and mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events.  During the mousemove the label needs to draw black wherever the label has covered.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: one way would be a grid of other smaller labels or pictureboxes which look like one big one and have the BGColor changed to black when the dragged label is ever over it.  Otherwise, you have a lot of work I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Form's OnPaint() method and then track the offset of the mouse Location from the point of drag origniation. This is essentially implementing an animated effect, so you will need to fire a redraw timer on the Label's drag start, paint the "tail" at a previous drag coordinate, repeating as your drag op moves the mouse coordinates past a certain threshold or certain speed. This will require some playing around to get the effect just right, but its fairly easy to implement.

Get started here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e40ahaz(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e40ahaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a background image in `picturebox`. Create a bitmap with `picturebox` dimensions:

```
Private pctBoxImage As Bitmap

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pctBoxImage = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

    pctBoxImage = CType(PictureBox1.BackgroundImage, Bitmap)
End Sub
```

If you dont have a background image just some `color`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pctBoxImage = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

    Dim objGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pctBoxImage)
    objGraphics.Clear(PictureBox1.BackColor)
    objGraphics.Dispose()
End Sub
```

When ever you move the label:

```
Dim pt as Point
'pt = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
pt = Label1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
pt = PictureBox1.PointToClient(pt)

Dim objGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pctBoxImage)
objGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, pt.X, pt.Y, 15, 15)
objGraphics.Dispose()

PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = pctBoxImage
```

valter